# Cascade insert couple of sub child relationships in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 4 entities mapped with OneToMany association. So entity `A (OneToMany ) -> B (OneToMany ) -> C (OneToMany )-> D`

I want to save the whole structure at once. So i've put `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` for each `OneToMany`. But it seems JPA don't want to save C and D associations, what I've accomplished is only B referenced to A, and C and D were saved without references.

when I save it with references like c.setB(b) and d.setC(c) it gives me error `object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing`

So is it possible to save all 4 entities with references, or should I do it step by step with a code?

A:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<B> b;
```

B:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "b", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<C> c;

@JoinColumn(name = "aId")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private A a;
```

C:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "c", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<D> d;

@JoinColumn(name = "bId")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private B b;
```

D:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "cId")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private C c;
```

Comment: Could you please share those 4 classes code. That will help in understanding where you are going wrong.

Comment: @vkrishna17 attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it was my mistake I was adding non existing reference in C entity. So it is possible) Hibernate did all 4 level cascade!